# Generate Gamma distributed values with upper bound

Tags: sampling, gamma-distribution

I need to generate `N` random numbers from a Gamma distribution, but with an upper bound `Pmax` using Matlab. Right now, I see two options.

1. Use `gaminv(A,B,P)` where `A` is the shape parameter and `B` is the scale parameter and `P=rand(N,1)*c` with `c` chosen such that `gaminv(A,B,c) = Pmax`. The problem is, that the `gaminv(A,B,P)` is in my case roughly 20x slower, than using `gamrnd(A,B,N)`.
2. I have written a function, that generates Gamma distributed values and takes those, smaller than `Pmax` and rejects all other values. I repeat this procedure, until I get `N` random numbers. The code is given further down. Problem with this version is, that for `Pmax` being small, this procedure takes very long (obviously).

Is there another way to sample (fast) Gamma distributed values with an upper bound?

**EDIT:** I forgot the Rejection Sampling. I will implement this, but am not really optimistic, that this will be faster.

---

**Code from section 2:**

> ```
> function P=gamrndbounded(A,B,N,Pmax)
> % computes N random values, sampled according to gamrnd(A,B) with the
> % property, that the stay below a value of pmax
> P = zeros(N,1);
> Accepted = 0;
> while(N-Accepted>0)
>     R = gamrnd(A,B,[N-Accepted,1]);
>     Accept = R(R<Pmax); % Use only values below Pmax
>     P(Accepted+1:Accepted+length(Accept)) = Accept; % Store those values
>     Accepted = Accepted + length(Accept);    
> end
> end
> ```

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: Dear @gung, I was not aware of the software related aspect. However, I do not think that my question is related to the sole purpose of software. I am asking for an efficient algorithm to sample random numbers from a truncated distribution. I only provided Matlab code to show the idea, but I would consider this problem to be not only related to Matlab, but to the procedure of sampling in general. Would you agree here?

Comment: If you aren't asking for code, it's fine. Saying you use MATLAB & showing some sample code is OK, you just want to make clear that the algorithm is what you're after.

Comment: You are completely right, I would be happy having an algorithm or a general procedure. Also, any reference is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want to simulate $X$ from som gamma distribution, conditional on $X \le \text{Pmax}$.  So one possibility would be to calculate the conditional distribution, and go from there. But there is a simpler way, based on inverse transform sampling. It does not have anything to do with the gama distribution, but is general.

So assume your distribution have cumulative distribution function (cdf) $F$, with inverse or quantile function $Q$. Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}} p=\P(X \le \text{Pmax}$. The inverse transform method consists in simulating $U$ with a standard uniform distrution, then $Q(U)$ will have the wanted distribution.

Now, to get the wanted conditional distribution, simply simulate $U_p$ from the uniform distribution on $[0, p]$ and return $Q(U_p)$. Using this in a gamma example I get:

[image]

R code:

```r
shape <- 3
scale <- 10

F <- function(x) pgamma(x, shape, scale=scale) 
f <- function(x) dgamma(x, shape, scale=scale) 
Q <- function(p) qgamma(p, shape, scale=scale)

Pmax <- 40
p <- F(Pmax) 

U <- runif(10000, min=0, max=p)
X <- Q(U)

f_cond  <- function(x) f(x) / F(Pmax) 

hist(X, prob=TRUE)
plot(f_cond, from=0, to=Pmax, col="red", add=TRUE)
```